# ObservableCollection populated by thread from ThreadPool

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

This is my approach to add items to ObservableCollection in a separate thread taken from ThreadPool.

As we know it will raise exception:

`This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.`

I know that this subject is quite popular here but I haven't found any solution that suits the situation described in the code below:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class Item
    {
        public string name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    class Container
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> internalList = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Container container = new Container();

        void addItems()
        {
            Item item = new Item() { name = "jack" };
            container.internalList.Add(item);

        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { this.addItems(); });
            MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = container.internalList;

        }
    }
}
```

What is the best solution for this problem here?

Thank you!

Comment: Either use WPF 4.5 where that kind of cross-thread activity is allowed or - even better - prepare the data in the background thread, return it and then populate the observable collection on UI thread...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
container.internalList.Add(item);
```

by

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => container.internalList.Add(item)));
```

This way the `Add` is executed on the `Dispatcher` thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can just get your data from a background thread as a `List` and then cast this list to an `ObservableCollection` as follows

```
List<SomeViewModel> someViewModelList = await GetYourDataAsListAsync();
ObservableCollection<SomeViewModel> Resources = new TypedListObservableCollection<SomeViewModel>(someViewModelList);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you set the properties of UI objects on the UI thread:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate()
{
    MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = container.internalList;
});
```

This will add the code within the curly braces onto the work items queue of the UI thread `Dispatcher`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the Collection on your class but in the Control that is binding to this collection from UI Thread.

There is something new in WPF 4.5:
http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/24/wpf-4-5-part-7-accessing-collections-on-non-ui-threads/

//Creates the lock object somewhere
`private static object _lock = new object();`

//Enable the cross acces to this collection elsewhere
`BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_persons, _lock);`

MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh198845(v=vs.110).aspx